# NAudio: get speaker setup per audio device

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I'm trying to get the channel count for Audio devices in the system.

I used the following code:

```
MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

foreach (MMDevice device in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.All))
{
   Console.WriteLine("*** {0}, {1}, {2}", device.FriendlyName, device.DeviceFriendlyName, device.State);
   if (device.State == DeviceState.Active) Console.WriteLine("   {0}", device.AudioEndpointVolume.Channels.Count);
}
```

I have two problems:

- **I'm missing the HDMI audio** device in the enumerable
- The **channel count seems always 2**, regardless of windows settings

I tried attaching two jacks (4 channels) into my audio connectors, and also setting the audio card to Stereo, Quadraphonic, and then to 5.1 Surround.

In all cases the channel count NAudio returns is 2.

I'm not trying to figure the number of connectors actually. I want to know the speaker setup windows is using for each device (Mono, Stereo, Quadraphonic, 5.1, 7.1).

Can someone help?

I am fine with having some other solution not related to NAudio to achieve the same thing.

Comment: you may try the GetChannelCount-method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370918(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: not exactly what i need. I dont care how many streams are in the audio, but what is the speaker configuration in windows control panel. I found out how to get it, with SharpDX.